# Why won't the attached code incorporating the load() command work?

Tags: r

The R code below features a function that incorporates the load() command. When run it reports that a saved object has been loaded, but the object doesn't appear in memory. I can get load() to work by itself, however.

```
# FUNCTION TO LOAD DATA
loaddat <- function(name) load(
  paste(
    paste(getwd(), name, sep = '/'),
   'RData', 
   sep = '.'
  ),
  verbose = T
)

# CREATE OBJECT
tmp <- rnorm(16)
# IN MEMORY
tmp
# SAVE OBJECT
save(tmp, file = 'tmp.RData')
# REMOVE OBJECT
rm('tmp')
# IT'S GONE
tmp

# USE MY FUNCTION, WHICH REPORTS THE OBJECT (RE)LOADED
loaddat('tmp')
# STILL GONE???
tmp

# USE THE load() FUNCTION
load('tmp.RData', verbose = T)
# (RE)LOADED
tmp

# END
```

Answer (score 1):

It is loaded into the function environment. Add a print statement to see this

```
loaddat <- function(name)  { 
  load( paste( paste(getwd(), name, sep = '/'), 'RData',  sep = '.'),
        verbose = TRUE)
  print(tmp)     
}
#Loading objects:
#  tmp
# [1] -1.2805219 -0.9895767 -0.6260367  3.0704998  1.4226676  2.3014122 -1.6997775  0.1187497
# [9]  0.3759539 -0.4102017  0.7820136 -0.5003354  1.4624261 -0.9128516 -0.6852421 -0.9394023
```

You could add a return statement to the function to return `tmp` (and you would also need to assign it). Otherwise you cam "*specify the environment where the data should be loaded*"; see `?load`. To return `tmp` to the global environment use `env=.GlobalEnv`.

```
loaddat <- function(name)  { 
  load( paste( paste(getwd(), name, sep = '/'), 'RData',  sep = '.'),
        verbose = TRUE, env=.GlobalEnv)   
}
```

Comment: Thanks...guess it's time to learn about environments!